# Astah: overlapping needless lifelines in sequence diagram after removing asynchronous calls

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, astah

I have recently started using Astah to create some UML models, especially sequence diagrams. Since I lack the expertise, I used asynchronous calls at two points that pointed back to an active lifeline which resulted in additional lifelines being put exactly ontop of the original lifeline; even after removing the asynchronous calls and replacing them with reply messages, the unnecessary lifelines remain:

[image: Overlapping lifelines in Astah sequence diagram]

The red arrows mark the visible spots where apparently new lifelines where added. I can select both of them, however, I can't remove them (at least not using the delete key or via the context menu which only shows one unrelated item). Is this by design and can anything be done to remove the additional lifelines without destroying the rest of the diagram?